# backand platform: how can I debug 'security actions` in `backand` service

Tags: javascript, backand

How can I debug `security actions` localy on my computer?

Maybe by using `backand action init`what can be write as
**Object Name** and **Action Name** 
for make it work

Comment: i figure now that `backand action init` is just for `on demand action` ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Backand! We don't currently offer you the capability to test Registered Users actions on your local machine. This is reserved for our server-side Node.js actions, which provide a script that facilitates testing the JavaScript action prior to uploading it to Backand. See our documentation for more information: http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/customactions/index.html